# Logical equality in C

Tags: c, boolean, equality

[It seems odd this doesn't exist, so apologies in advance if it's a duplicate]

I want to test for logical equality in C.  In other words, I want to know whether two values would be equal if both were converted in the normal way associated with logical expressions.

In C99, I think that

```
(bool)a == (bool)b
```

gives what I want.  Is that correct?  What is the normal way of writing this in traditional C?

Comment: Plain traditional C doesn't have bool type.

Comment: err, guys?  you read the q?  i know traditional C doesn't have bool.  that's why i am asking how you would write that in traditional C.  also, Als, `==` will return false for `1 == 2`, which is not what i want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You typically see this:

```
if ((a == 0) == (b == 0))
```

Or

```
if (!!a == !!b)
```

Since `!!a` evaluates to 1 if a is nonzero and 0 otherwise.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

In C, zero is false. If you want to convert any value to its boolean equivalent, the standard way (well, except that there's almost never a need for it) is to prefix an expression with `!!` , as in `!!a`. In the case of your expression,
`!!a == !!b`
may be simplified to 
`!a == !b`

Comment: when *is* there a need for it?

Comment: When a and b might have different non-zero values, and you want to know if they will evaluate to the same boolean in a subsequent control-flow test, such as `if()`.

Answer (score 2):

In pre-C99 C, the tradiitional, idiomatic way to "cast to bool" is with `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `(bool)` in traditional c. True/False is handled using `int`s. You can check for boolean equality with

```
a ? b : !b
```

Comment: I meant traditional c, not c99.

Comment: This doesn't check for equality. This does something else.

Comment: @H2CO3 - it's kind of weird, but looks ok to me.  can you give an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: This is an excellent answer; the OP was about *traditional* C. (the C without Bull). It does work in the case where a "pseudo bool" type of value is needed, as in an `if(...)` clause.

Comment: `if (a) { return b; } else { return !b; }` means if a is true, then return b is true, otherwise return !b is true. This is the correct behavior, and makes no assumptions about the behavior of `!!b`

Comment: what assumptions does `!!b` imply?

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm not sure I'd agree that this is an *excellent* answer.  I agree that it works, but it's a lot less intuitive than some of the other solutions.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: read the OP: it is about original/traditional (pre c99 shit) C.